# Why retrieve Data is not Update in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, oracle11g

I have three JSP as follows:

1. Employee_vendor_approve.jsp : which is retrieve Employee Details
2. update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp: Which is take reference of Employee_vendor_approve.jsp page for upadate process
3. update_process_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp: is update retrieve data

from point 1 i can able to retrieve data but i unable to proceed point 2 and 3. where is problem i unable to find, when i click update link on Employee_vendor_approve.jsp, update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp showing blank here is my code

Employee_vendor_approve.jsp:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Employee and vendor approve Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>FIRST_NAME </td>
                <td>LAST_NAME</td>
                <td>ORGANIZATION_NAME</td>
                <td>EMPLOYEE_ID</td>
                <td>Approve</td>
                <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
            <%
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con==DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@173.18.114.213:1821:godb","ex","xe");

            statement=con.createStatement();
            String Sql="SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ORGANISATION_NAME,EMPLOYEE_ID,APPROVE from REGISTRATION_EMPLOYEE where role in ('Employee','Vendor')";
            resultSet=statement.executeQuery(Sql);       

         while(resultSet.next()){
          %>
           <tr>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("FIRST_NAME")%></td>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("LAST_NAME")%></td>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("ORGANISATION_NAME")%></td>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID")%></td>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("APPROVE")%></td>
              <td>
               <a href="update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID")%>">update</a>               
            </td>  
        </tr>   
        <%
    }
      //con.close();
    %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp:

```
     <html>
        <body>
<form method="post" action="update_process_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp">

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
             <th>FIRST_NAME </th>
                <th>LAST_NAME</th>
                <th>ORGANIZATION_NAME</th>
                <th>EMPLOYEE_ID</th>
                <th>Approve</th>
        </tr>
        <%
        String employee_id=request.getParameter("employee_id");

        int sumcount=0;
        try
        {
               Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@173.18.114.213:1821:godb","ex","xe");

         Statement st=con.createStatement();

          String query="SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ORGANISATION_NAME,EMPLOYEE_ID,APPROVE from REGISTRATION_EMPLOYEE where EMPLOYEE_ID="+employee_id;

          ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);

          while(rs.next())
          {
              %>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" name="FIRST_NAME" value="<%=rs.getString("FIRST_NAME")%>"> </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="LAST_NAME" value="<%=rs.getString("LAST_NAME")%>"> </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="ORGANISATION_NAME" value="<%=rs.getString("ORGANISATION_NAME")%>"> </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="APPROVE" value="<%=rs.getString("APPROVE")%>"> </td>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="EMPLOYEE_ID" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;"></td>
              </tr>

             <%  }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        %>
    </table>    
</form>
        </body>
 </html>
```

update_process_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@173.18.114.213:1821:godb","ex","xe");

        String EMPLOYEE_ID=request.getParameter("EMPLOYEE_ID");
        String first_name=request.getParameter("FIRST_NAME");
        String Last_name=request.getParameter("LAST_NAME");
        String ORGANISATION_NAME=request.getParameter("ORGANISATION_NAME");
        String Approve_status=request.getParameter("APPROVE");

        if (EMPLOYEE_ID!=null) 
        {


        // Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        int personID = Integer.parseInt(EMPLOYEE_ID);       
        try

        {
            String Sql="update REGISTRATION_EMPLOYEE set APPROVE='Y' where EMPLOYEE_ID="+EMPLOYEE_ID;
            ps=con.prepareStatement(Sql);
            ps.setString(1, Approve_status);
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0)
            {
               out.print("Record Updated Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
        out.print("There is a problem in updating Record.");
        }  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you write `Connection con==DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@173.18.114.213:1821:godb","ex","xe");` it will have errors

Comment: @lucumt: i updated my code but still only i get header's not actual value in update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp page

Comment: hey,guys you need to output the jsp executed sql and run it directly to check if it has values

Comment: it has value brother for more clear understand i update images also

Comment: I have added answer ,you can check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Employee_vendor_approve.jsp:** you set parameter name called `id`

```
<a href="update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID")%>">update</a>
```

but in **update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp** you get the parameter via `employee_id`

```
String employee_id=request.getParameter("employee_id");
```

They do not keep the same,so you get empty value.In order to solve this,you can change it to below:

```
String employee_id=request.getParameter("id");//using id instead of employee_id
```

---

To the problem you can not update data,it's also due to you fetch wrong value in **update_employeeVendorLoginCredentials.jsp**:

```
 <td><input type="hidden" name="EMPLOYEE_ID" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"></td> // you have get the wrong value for id
```

In order to let it work,change it as below:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="EMPLOYEE_ID" value="<%=rs.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID")%>"></td>
```

Comment: brother i updated your given suggestion and now value fetching but still i unable to do update when click save option

Comment: its working properly i forget to mentioned to right request.getParameter("btnsubmit")!=null this line